# TypeError not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I am trying to make matrix 2 dimension and then I took 1 of the matrix's element into comparison. for the record, i declare my matrix with type integer and I do comparison with integer too. what happen with this ? this is my matrix declaration :

```
Matkul = [str]*10
for i in range (10) :
    Matkul[i] = [int]*2
```

then this is my comparison between integer element in matkul with integer :

```
x = Matkul[i][1]
if   x >= 85 :
        return 'A'
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you use `str` you don't create a string, you just copy **what** a string is, the same thing for `int`.
If you want to create an integer use `int()` (and `str()` for string), or simply say:

```
Matkul = []
for _ in range (10) : # It's better practice to use _ (underscore) instead of i in this case to specify that you won't actually use it
    Matkul.append([0]*2)
```

or even, if you understand  list comprehension :

```
Matkul = [[0]*2 for _ in range(10)]
```